# Delete button for list items and strikethrough functionality (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here's a bug in my code ([CodeSandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/todo-app-ymft1?file=/src/App.js)). I am able to put a strikethrough when there is a click on the list item name but when there are more than one item in the list with some items with strikethrough and I delete any item then the app behaves not according to what I want. How to fix this bug?

THANKS IN ADVANCE!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw the problem is you are using `uuid.v4()` in the render. So every time rerender, the `ListItem` become new and old state `isStrike` will lost.

You can make sure the key is unique and not change when rerender.

Here is a solution you can try: https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-rgb-w45b3?file=/src/App.js

Comment: nice find :) didn't see that

Answer (score 1):

You need to hold the striked list items in an array. Check the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-browser-y1m3n?file=/src/ListItem.jsx)